# Encrypted swap no longer being activated at boot after removing and re-adding it

Tags: encryption, swap

I have a Ubuntu 13.04 system using encryption for /, /home, and swap. This used to work flawlessly, but then I needed to resize the swap partition. After doing that, and manually trying to set it up, the swap partition no longer gets activated at boot.

I can however activate it by doing a:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda6 sda_crypt
# swapon -a
```

after boot.

I have a feeling that I am missing something like a commandline option for the kernel. Does anyone have a hunch?

For completeness, here are my fstab and crypttab:

```
# cat /etc/crypttab 
sda6_crypt UUID=dc259cc3-cb4a-44d2-8b1e-3636ef294b94 none luks,swap
sdb5_crypt UUID=a8f5cfdd-a17c-448f-8ecf-24ba48d843c1 none luks
sdb7_crypt UUID=bd50ceca-8bff-421d-b91a-783659fedca6 none luks
# egrep -v '^(#|$)' /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/sdb5_crypt /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=04ad0dee-887f-400f-bf87-2086bd3e4cbf /backup         ext4     defaults        0       2
UUID=06be7d34-7990-4dbe-9c29-e0fec9812149 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/sdb7_crypt /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/sda6_crypt none            swap    sw              0       0
#
```

EDIT: I already tried "update-initramfs -u -k all" and "dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc" to resolve the problem - this did not help.

Comment: Did you update your initramfs after altering the configuration files? `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: @gertvdijk: Yup, forgot to mention that. Will edit my question.

Comment: Not trying to state the obvious, but did you verify the UUID? After changing the size of the partition this may have changed. Run `sudo blkid` to verify.

Comment: @gertvdijk: yup, the UUID is correct. I deleted the old entries in fstab and crypttab when I resized the partition, and added new ones afterwards.